# Is there a Drupal shopping cart interface for Bitcoin?

Tags: shopping-cart-interface, ecommerce

Is there any Drupal SCI for Bitcoin available? Either tied into Ubercart or, more preferably,  Drupal Commerce.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it may be too time dependent. Do you want to know the answer to this question now, or when people read and answer it 10 months from now?

Comment: hmmm, can we not ask any time dependent questions here? Ideally I'd like to know now, and if things have changed in 10 months, I'd like to know that too :)

Comment: A lot of questions are just as time dependant as this one. The difference here is that the title ("what is the _current_ status?") makes it much more obvious. I suggest changing this title to something that doesn't sound as time dependant.

Comment: I edited the title and the question so that it doesn't say "current status" anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have a look at [uc_bitcoin](http://www.nostate.com/3955/uc_bitcoin-a-bitcoin-payment-method-for-ubercartdrupal/) by Mike Gogulski that seems be what you are looking for. A word of caution though: The GitHub code has not been updated since November 2010, it is for Drupal 6.x (has not been tried on D7) and Mike states that "There’s probably not going to be an update for a long while, either, so fork and code away". Anyway, here's some info about it:

> A Bitcoin payment method for the Ubercart shopping cart for Drupal.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Generates a new bitcoin address for every order
> - Provides payment address to customer on site at checkout, plus in a
>     subsequent email
> - Configurable timeout after which unpaid transactions will be
>     canceled automatically
> - Configurable number of Bitcoin network confirmations after which an
>     order is considered paid
> - HTTP or HTTPS access to bitcoind

There is also [a project by Darrell Duane](http://drupal.org/project/uc_bitcoin) that is based on Mike's project. There is no download available yet and the project page was updated in June 2011.

Answer (score 5):

Now you can try Bitpay's Ubercart plugin:

https://github.com/bitpay/ubercart-plugin

Answer (score 2):

A module is now available for Drupal Commerce : [Commerce Bitcoin](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_bitcoin). Still in Dev though !

Answer (score 1):

Closest thing I have seen is  Community Accounting  for Drupal
http://drupal.org/project/mutual_credit
"An all-embracing and flexible package which includes a mutual credit ledger, super-configurable transaction forms and displays, including several views and blocks. It can be used as a digital back-end for paper money projects, or to run an entire LETS, Timebank, or several in parallel. With a little tweaking, it can manage currencies conforming to a wide range of designs. Autopayments can be done with a little glue code."

The only other plugin I know of is the one for OpenCart for bit-pay
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3119&path=20